# How to aggregate counts in sections of a fixed number of hours

Tags: python

I have a sequence of pairs, the first element in each pair is a string representing a `datetime` and the second a number. I would like to split up the dates into consecutive periods of `x` hours and sum the corresponding numbers in each hour. If `x == 1` I can do this with:

```
from dateutil import parser
hour_total = {}
for i in range(len(sequence_of_pairs)):
    dtime = parser.parse(sequence_of_pairs[i][0])
    hour_total[dtime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00')] += sequence_of_pairs[i][1]
```

At the end `hour_total` is a dict with the sum of the numbers for each hour.

How can I extend this to work for arbitrary positive values of `x`?

---

A very small example covering just a few hours:

```
sequence_of_pairs = [('2020-02-01 00:03:09+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 00:11:18+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 00:16:20+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 00:18:54+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 00:18:59+00:00', -0.3), ('2020-02-01 00:20:35+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 00:21:34+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 00:29:04+00:00', -0.1), ('2020-02-01 00:47:56+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 00:47:57+00:00', -0.5), ('2020-02-01 00:53:05+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 00:56:20+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 00:58:56+00:00', 0.2), ('2020-02-01 01:00:50+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 01:08:22+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 01:28:24+00:00', 0.16666666666666666), ('2020-02-01 01:55:50+00:00', -0.625), ('2020-02-01 02:16:07+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 02:35:12+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 02:41:52+00:00', 0.7), ('2020-02-01 03:37:53+00:00', 0.43333333333333335), ('2020-02-01 05:00:00+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 05:26:44+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 05:58:33+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 06:02:29+00:00', -0.14583333333333334), ('2020-02-01 06:11:32+00:00', -0.65), ('2020-02-01 06:13:54+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 06:21:40+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 06:25:48+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 06:50:21+00:00', 0.6), ('2020-02-01 06:54:03+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 07:07:33+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 07:11:06+00:00', -0.5), ('2020-02-01 07:12:46+00:00', 0.3), ('2020-02-01 07:13:05+00:00', -0.5), ('2020-02-01 07:16:03+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 07:25:51+00:00', -0.25), ('2020-02-01 07:38:13+00:00', -0.10606060606060608), ('2020-02-01 07:47:54+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 07:50:19+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 07:51:31+00:00', -0.125), ('2020-02-01 07:53:16+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 07:54:49+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 07:57:59+00:00', 0.0), ('2020-02-01 07:58:55+00:00', -0.1185897435897436)]
```

if `x == 1` the output is:

```
{'2020-02-01 00:00': -0.7,
 '2020-02-01 01:00': -0.45833333333333337,
 '2020-02-01 02:00': 0.7,
 '2020-02-01 03:00': 0.43333333333333335,
 '2020-02-01 05:00': 0.0,
 '2020-02-01 06:00': -0.19583333333333341,
 '2020-02-01 07:00': -1.2996503496503498}
```

Comment: can you provide an example input and the matching expected output?

Comment: @mozway Done. I hope it is clear.

Comment: thanks, are the dates ordered? What should be the keys for example if x = 1.3?

Comment: Specifically, is `sequence_of_pairs` ordered by increasing time? Can I rely on hour(sequence_of_pairs[0][0]) being the first hour in all cases?

Comment: @mozway yes they are  ordered.  For x=1.3 it should be the sum of the values in minutes 0 to 78, then 79 to 156 etc.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes sequence_of_pairs is ordered by increasing time.  Some hours might be completely missing in the data though.

Comment: So you basically want to consider datetime ranges and sum all values that fall into a specific range. The question is, when do the datetime ranges start and when do they end? I mean, what defines those ranges? In the case of 1 hour intervals, it is clear, but what would the result be for `x=2` or `x=3`? In other words, for an arbitrary value of `x`, how do you compute the key from a given datetime string?

Comment: @a_guest assume the starts at midnight and just look at two hour intervals for x=2 and three hour intervals for x=3? Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @graffe Not exactly, I suppose you mean midnight w.r.t. the first date encountered in the list of dates? It would be good, if you could add this to your sample code, i.e. how to compute that start time: `dt_start = ?`.

Answer (score 2):

##### relative time to first item of each group

Here is a working solution that accumulates from the last valid item, it uses the first valid date as key (can be modified if needed):

```
from dateutil import parser
from collections import defaultdict

hour_total = defaultdict(int) # defaultdict(lambda: 123) for a different default value
x = 1.3


key = sequence_of_pairs[0][0]
last = parser.parse(key)
for date, value in sequence_of_pairs:
    d = parser.parse(date)
    if (d-last).total_seconds() > 3600*x:
        key = date
        last = d
    hour_total[key] += value
    
dict(hour_total)
```

output:

```
{'2020-02-01 00:03:09+00:00': -0.7,
 '2020-02-01 01:28:24+00:00': 0.24166666666666659,
 '2020-02-01 03:37:53+00:00': 0.43333333333333335,
 '2020-02-01 05:00:00+00:00': -0.7958333333333334,
 '2020-02-01 06:21:40+00:00': -0.4560606060606061,
 '2020-02-01 07:47:54+00:00': -0.2435897435897436}
```

##### grouped by absolute time relative to first date

```
from dateutil import parser
from collections import defaultdict

hour_total = defaultdict(int)
x = 1.3

first = parser.parse(sequence_of_pairs[0][0])
for date, value in sequence_of_pairs:
    d = parser.parse(date)
    group = (d-first).total_seconds() // (x*3600)
    hour_total[f'{round(group*x*60)}min'] += value
    
dict(hour_total)
```

output:

```
{'0min': -0.7,
 '78min': -0.45833333333333337,
 '156min': 1.1333333333333333,
 '234min': 0.0,
 '312min': -0.7958333333333334,
 '390min': -0.4560606060606061,
 '468min': -0.2435897435897436}
```

Comment: `lambda: 0` is idiomatically written as `int`, which has a default value of zero exactly for this sort of application.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes very true, I wrote it this way to explicitly show the default value ;)

Comment: Also, why not just use `(date - sequence_of_pairs[0][0]).total_seconds() // x * 3600`. That will require zero branching and won't be subject to drift.

Comment: @MadPhysicist because I interpreted the question differently when I first read it, but it seems that that a fixed range might be what OP is after. I'll update the post with both approaches ;)

Comment: You can use `group` directly as a key. Why multiply by 60 and add a suffix to a string when you already have a perfectly good integer to play with?

Comment: Because it's just an example, and easy to adapt to OP's needs

Comment: You can just assume time starts at midnight.

Comment: @graffe you can use whatever starting point you want, just define it as `first` ;)

Comment: @mozway Is there a simple way to set `first` to midnight on the day of the first datetime?

Comment: Use `first = parser.parse(sequence_of_pairs[0][0].split()[0])` this will remove the time info and default to midnight